# How to stop Emacs from opening binary files

Tags: emacs, elisp

How can I make Emacs give me a warning if I am about to open a file that does not contain text?

Example:
When I edit a c++ source code in file `test.cpp` and compile it as an executable `test` in the same directory, i often accidentally open the binary file `test`.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs cannot warn you that a file does not contain text unless it either *does* open it (so that it can see what the contents are), or otherwise asks some other program to find out (perhaps using something like the Unix `file` command).

The problem with the latter approach is that Emacs *can* handle many kinds of binary file, so you would then need that external program to also know which kinds of binary file Emacs recognises, *including* support added by add-on libraries, which can vary dynamically and per-user.

I don't think there are any good options there.

What is it specifically that you are trying to avoid?

**Edit:**

As the required test for the given example is based only upon filenames, the following would be a viable approach.

```el
(defvar my-find-file-check-source-extensions
  '(".cpp" ".cc"))

(defadvice find-file-read-args (after my-find-file-read-args-check-source)
  (let* ((filename (car ad-return-value))
         (source-filename
          (catch 'source-file-exists
            (mapc (lambda (ext)
                    (let ((source-filename (concat filename ext)))
                      (when (file-exists-p source-filename)
                        (throw 'source-file-exists source-filename))))
                  my-find-file-check-source-extensions)
            nil)))

    (and source-filename
         (not (y-or-n-p (format "Source file %s detected. Are you sure you \
want to open %s? " source-filename filename)))
         (error "find-file aborted by user"))))

(ad-activate 'find-file-read-args)
```

Comment: I edited by question by adding an example.